# Attempted to call function from namespace - Silex PHP

Tags: php, function, class, namespaces, silex

I have two doubts about my development in Silex PHP.

**usersController.php**

```
namespace myworkplaces\controllers;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use myworkplaces\models;

class usersController implements ControllerProviderInterface {

    public function connect(Application $app) {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controllers->put('/login', array($this, 'login'))->bind('login');
        return $controllers;
    }
    public function login(Application $app, Request $request) {
        $email = $app->escape($request->get('email'));
        $password = $app->escape($request->get('password'));

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            return $app->json(array ('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'El email no tiene el formato correcto.'), 202);
        if (strlen($password) < 5)
            return $app->json(array ('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'La contraseña no puede ser menor a 6 carácteres.'), 202);

        if (models\usersModel::checkLogin($app, $email, $password)) {
            return $app->json(array ('type' => 'info', 'message' => '¡Ten un buen día!'), 201);
        } else {
            return $app->json(array ('type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Error en la autentificación.'), 202);
        }
    }}
```

**usersModel.php**

```
namespace myworkplaces\models;

class usersModel {
    function checkEmail($app, $email) {
        if (($app['db']->users)->findOne([ 'email' => $email ], [ 'projection' => [ 'email' => 1 ] ]) != NULL) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function getDataUser($app, $id) {
        return ($app['db']->users)->findOne([ '_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id) ]);
    }
    function checkLogin($app, $email, $password) {
        if (!checkEmail($app, $email))
            return false;
        if (password_verify($password, ($app['db']->users)->findOne([ 'email' => $email ], [ 'projection' => [ 'hashPassword' => 1 ] ])['hashPassword'])) {
            $user = getDataUser($app, (string)getID($email));
            $app['session']->set('user', array('id' => (string)$user['_id'], 'email' => $user['email'], 'username' => $user['username'], 'superadmin' => $user['superadmin'], 'adminPlaces' => $user['adminPlaces']));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }}
```

To access the checkLogin() function inside the myworkplaces\models namespace and within the class usersModel, I could only access using this call models\usersModel::checkLogin(), and I do not think it's the right thing. Should not I be able to call the function with models\usersModel\checkLogin()?

The second problem is in the function checkLogin, I want to call the checkEmail function inside the same namespace and within the same class, however with a call like checkEmail () you should be able to call it without error. The error that occurs is, Attempted to call function "checkEmail" from namespace "myworkplaces\models". Where is the problem?

I use the autoload of composer

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myworkplaces\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your above code is not fine, it has error, You want a fix of your above code.

Comment: @sahil-gulati If my code has errors, all comments are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am assuming no other syntax errors and your class loader is working fine.

In your `controller.php`

**Change this to:**

```
if (models\usersModel::checkLogin($app, $email, $password)) {
```

**This:**

```
if (\myworkplaces\models\usersModel::checkLogin($app, $email, $password)) {
```

In your `usersModel.php`

**Change this to:**

```
function checkEmail($app, $email) {
```

**This:**

```
public function static checkEmail($app, $email) {
```

**Change this to:**

```
if (!checkEmail($app, $email))
```

**This:**

```
if (!self::checkEmail($app, $email))
```

Comment: Ok, what you say with the code, is that in PHP the functions of classes not instantiated must be static, unlike other languages.

Thank you very much, I hope it helps a better understand to other people if they have the same doubts.

Comment: In the controller.php you would not have to call the function \myworkplaces\models\usersModel::checkLogin (), as there is a use myworkplaces\models". With models\usersModel::checkLogin() it works. My question was whether it was right to use it like that. And as for the change of the usersModel.php it is not necessary the public in the static function, because by default it is already public.

Comment: yes its perfectly fine. no issues with that you can use it like `models\usersModel::checkLogin()` Welcome ...:)